# Why is logstash creating jffi nnnnnn.tmp files in windows\temp folder

Tags: jruby, logstash

I'm running logstash as a windows service, each time i start the service it seems to generate a large number of jffi temp files in the Windows\Temp folder.  I had a quick hunt around and it it appears these are generated by JRuby, has anyone else encountered the same problem and is there a way to switch this off?

using logstash-1.4.0 on Windows7 (64) and Windows Server 2003 Enterprise 64.

I'm a newbie to logstash, struggling to get this working on Windows, almost all the examples I encounter seem to be for unix.

Any advice greatly appreciated....

Comment: Possibly a bug in JRuby. Some quick searching turned up related issues: [JRUBY-4385](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4385), [LOGSTASH-2151](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-2151), and [jruby #1237 on GitHub](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1237). Logstash 1.4.0 comes bundled with a slightly outdated JRuby version 1.7.11. Try running with 1.7.12?